# exit code of grep in trap where the script is launched by upstart service

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep, upstart, trap

Recently I encountered a problem in ubuntu upstart and trap in Bash shell.

I use ubuntu 12.04. The upstart script(/etc/init/player.conf) is:

```
start on (local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [06]

script
    /tmp/test.sh
end script
```

The `/tmp/test.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN="token"
TOKEN_FILE="/tmp/token"
OUTPUT_FILE="/tmp/test_exit"
func()
{
    grep "$TOKEN" "$TOKEN_FILE"; echo $? >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"; exit 0
}

trap 'trap "" INT TERM QUIT EXIT; func' INT TERM QUIT EXIT

rm -f "$OUTPUT_FILE"
echo "$TOKEN" > "$TOKEN_FILE"

grep "$TOKEN" "$TOKEN_FILE"; echo $? >> "$OUTPUT_FILE";

sleep 1000

exit 0
```

The test procedure:

```
$sudo service player start
$sudo service player stop
$cat /tmp/test_exit
0
2
```

My question is, why the second result is 2, since the file(/tmp/token) is not changed, the grep should find the string("token") in that file("/tmp/token").

Comment: You can enable debug mode using ` bash -x /tmp/test.sh >/tmp/debug.log 2>&1` so that you can trace that..

Comment: If I execute /tmp/test.sh and wait until it's finished or terminate it with SIGKILL or SIGINT, the result is "0 0", only when I use upstart service to start/stop it the result will be different

Comment: what happens if you change the grep to `grep -q` or redirect the output?

Comment: both *grep -q* and redirection give "0 0", but why is that??

Comment: my suspicion/theory is that the exit code of 2 (error) is because when the script runs from upstart there's no stdout to write the output of grep to

Comment: I use `[ -t 1]` and `[ -t 2 ]` to detect availability of stdout and stderr inside/outside trap, and both of the test say that stdout and stderr do exist. However, if I execute `exec >&- 2>&-` beforehand in another script, `grep` does return 2